# Problem with the proof of a theorem in the field of permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

My question is about the proof of the Theorem $3.4B$ of the book "Permutation groups" by J. Dixon and B. Mortimer.

[image]

I understand the proof with assumption (i) but my problem is with assumption (ii), I mean where we don't know that $G$ is finite or not and we just know that the point stabilizers $G_\alpha$ are abelian. In the proof of this part, it is proven that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. I know that if $K$ be a subgroup of $G$, it is normal and regular. But I don't understand why it is also abelian and each nontrivial elements of $K$ has the same order.

I will be so thankful for any answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $K \setminus \{ 1 \}$ are all conjugate by elements of $G_\alpha$, so they all have the same order.

Since $G$ is $2$-transitive, for $\alpha,\beta \in \Omega$, there exists $t \in G$ containing the transposition $(\alpha,\beta)$ and, since $\alpha^2$ fixes both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have $t^2=1$, so $t$ is an involution.

If $t$ has no fixed points, then $t \in K$, so all elements of $K$ have order $2$, and hence $K$ is abelian.

Otherwise, $t$ fixes a point $\alpha$. For any $1 \ne x \in K$, let $y = x^{-1}x^t$. Then $y^t = y^{-1}$. Now, for any $1 \ne z \in K$, there exists $u \in G_\alpha$ with $y^u=z$. Then, since $G_\alpha$ is abelian, $z^t = y^{ut} = y^{tu} = (y^{-1})^u = z^{-1}$. So, in its conjugation action on $K$, $t$ inverts every element of $K$, which implies that $K$ is abelian.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful and nice answer again. In the last line of your proof, is it essential to know that $K$ is finite to say  "since there is a fixed-point-free automorphism of order 2 on $K$, then  $K$ is abelian"? I don't know that $K$ is finite or not!

Comment: Yes you are right. I have changed it to a different argument, which uses the fact that $G_\alpha$ is abelian.